# I can't build pyrit

Tags: linux, networking, terminal, kali-linux, python

When I use command line

> python2 setup.py build

This Error Will Shown In Terminal Is Any One Face This Problem.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Comment: I tried This soultion but it's the same problem.